# Reporting Services 2000 - email different report to many people

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2000

Reporting Services 2000 Standard Edition (currently RTM but hope to have SP2 soon).

I have a report which takes in a parameter - PlantID

I'd like to email a pdf of this report every month to the 80 different plant managers

So I have a table:

```
PlantID    ManagerEmail
1          BillySmith@company.com
2          FredJones@asdf.com
3          JohnLonestar@rrr.com
```

I can currently setup a subscription to email a report to multiple users each month (which uses the SQL agent).

However I want to specify the input parameter of the report (PlantID) to the recipient of the email (ManagerEmail).

Ideas on how to do this?  My current thought is to build a C# app which calls the URL of the RS with the correct input parameter in it.  Then gets the pdf back, then emails from C#.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Data-Driven Subscription would be the ideal answer, but I see that Data-Driven Subscriptions are not available in RS 2000 Standard.

[This Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataDrivenSubscriptions.aspx) discusses how to use a stored procedure to tweak a Reporting Services subscription and insert your own values into the respective fields.

Comment: This looks great... just nipping off to give it a test.. many thanks Erick.

Answer (score 0):

That would be my first thought on how to do it also.

You might also be able to set up a scheduled stored proc to execute it for you, but that's more of a guess than an experienced suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Jared.. I may have to go that route..!  Unless anything other devious plans come to mind.

Cheers